# Spring boot Data MongoDB Sample database

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I was using Out of the box Maven spring boot MongoDB sample.
Please can someone tell where is the configuration of database- "test"
How can I change to connect to a different Mongo database?

Comment: It would help if you can share the relevant part of the pom.xml (if that still is how it works)

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/   the link and example. I want to know where "test"  DB specified

Comment: You can [edit] your question when you want to improve it, for example to create an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add spring.data.mongodb.database=DatabaseName in your application.properties file in classpath. Refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: Agree there are ways - mongo namespace in config or Template in code. But I could not understand how that code was able to connect to 'test', where is it specified in the example

Comment: MongoDB default database is 'test' (Refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/). Even when u connect through shell it will be connected to test db. Spring is just establishing the connection to mongo. The shell connects to test database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
   .....
   .....

   @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mytest";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("localhost" , 27017 );
    }
```

Comment: I prefer to use the properties file. profiles are great.